# Filter listview in other language beyond english

Tags: android, listview, locale

I have a `ListView` populated by `String[]`. I have an `EditText` to filter the listview and search. The thing is that when i search in English and the Strings are in English everything is fine, but when i translate the Strings in other language(e.g. Greek) the filter does not work.

My code:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView lv;
    private String[] myItems;
    private EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.categoryList);
        myItems = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("items");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CategoryActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.filterText);
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                CategoryActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The myItems String[] is populated with Strings(in Greek).

Any help?? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not have to do with the language. If you Strings are written in Greek and your keyboard has the Greek Language then you should be able to filter the `listView` in Greek and so on.

Hope it helps!!!